# Keep getting error on Symfony after installing JsFormValidatorBundle

Tags: symfony, composer-php, bundle

After installing JsFormValidatorBundle, I keep getting the error bellow when I try to open my page on localhost. I installed the bundle following the instruction on https://github.com/formapro/JsFormValidatorBundle, composer installed the bundle successfully. My Symfony version is the 2.8. And my composer is updated.

> InvalidArgumentException in FormPass.php line 59:
>   Tagged form type extension must have the extended type configured using the extended_type/extended-type attribute, none was configured for the "fp_js_form_validator.extension" service.

I tried to add this information at `app/config/services.yml`, but did not work:

```
fp_js_form_validator.extension:
    class: Fp\JsFormValidatorBundle\Form\Extension\FormExtension
    tags:
        - { name: form.type_extension, alias='form', extended_type: Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\FileType }
```

Thanks

Comment: It is not look like they support version 2.8. Repository is an old repository. I use https://github.com/boekkooi/JqueryValidationBundle it is perfectly working with Sf 2.8

Comment: Just tried to use this bundle, but I am now getting a javascript error: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'validator.settings')

Comment: Add form names to your forms

Comment: I cant believe that was the reason for the error. Thanks a lot Jason and FZE. Now it is working!